# Jquery replace an image on expand/collapse

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following page with HTML/Jquery that expands/collapses content on the header click.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body style="font-family:Arial; font-size:16; color:#003c6e; background-color:#E8E5D5;" link="#003c6e" vlink="#003c6e" alink="#003c6e">

<h3 style="font-size:22; font-weight: normal;">
First Header
</h3>

<h3>
    Section Header
</h3>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
                <img class="PfeilR" src="Pfeil_rechts_blau.png" style="height:12px;">
                <img class="PfeilO" src="Pfeil_oben_weiss.png" style="height:12px;">

            <span>
                Expander Header
            </span>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <hr>
            My content
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
                <img class="PfeilR" src="Pfeil_rechts_blau.png" style="height:12px;">
                <img class="PfeilO" src="Pfeil_oben_weiss.png" style="height:12px;">

            <span>
                Expander Header
            </span>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <hr>
            More content
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script>
    $(".header").click(function () {

        $header = $(this);
        //getting the next element
        $content = $header.next();
        //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
        $content.slideToggle(500, function () {
            //execute this after slideToggle is done


            //TODO change image of header based on visibility of content div


        });

    });
</script>

</body>
```

I want to be able to show hide one of the two images (PfeilR/PfeilO) when the content section is shown/hidden, but only for the clicked content section not all of them.

Here is the CSS if needed

```
.container .content {
display: none;
padding-top : 10px;
padding-bottom : 20px;}
```

and this is what the application currently looks like with both images shown always

[image]

I know this might be a duplicate Question, and appologise for this, but i dont understand JQuery enough yet to adapt other examples.

Any help is appreciated. Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give the 2 images as 2 classes for the span and change the class when clicked.

Assuming PfeilO is the arrow you want to see initially

```
 <div class="header PfeilO">
     <span>
         Header
     </span>
</div>
```

and add the below line in your script inside the click handler

```
$(this).toggleClass("PfeilR").toggleClass("Pfeil0")
```

OR

Another solution is to hide images when clicked. You could add this to your script inside the click handler

```
$(this).find(".PfeilR").toggle().end().find(".PfeilO").toggle()
```

also add the css assuming that you want to see PfeilO by default.

```
.PfeilR{
   display : none
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use bootstrap accordian

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

or if you want it in jquery here is the code below.

Html Part

```
<div class="faq_section_body">
         <h3 class="active">Till when can I claim my Theft Insurance?</h3>
         <div style="">
            <p>your answer here</p>
         </div>
         <h3>What is the customer care number?</h3>
         <div style="display: none;">
            <p>Our toll free number is 123456789</p>
         </div>
      </div>
```

JQuery Part

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.faq_section_body h3').each(function() {
                    var tis = $(this),
                        state = false,
                        answer = tis.next('div').slideUp();
                    tis.click(function() {
                            $('.faq_section_body div').not($(this).next('div')).not('.clearfix').hide(500);
                            state = !state;
                            answer.slideToggle(state);
                            tis.toggleClass('active',state);
                        });
                });
    });
```

Hope this will help you.